# Validating a Form without redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii, fancybox

I created app with yii and I need to load a view form in Fancy-box.
I did that but my problem is when I click on the submit button the form redirects me to the controller action without validating the form.

How to validate the form without the redirect inside Fancy-box?

My view:

```
<?php
    $config = array( 
);

$this->widget('application.extensions.fancybox.EFancyBox', array(
'target'=>'#getaction',
'config'=>$config,));

echo CHtml::link('Add Section',array('section/create'),array('id'=>'getaction'));
?>
```

FormView  _from  from call from another view

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'section-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Controller :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Section;       

    if(isset($_POST['Section']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Section'];
        if($model->validate())
        //// Do Som code here 
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: check your error console may be some jquery error

Comment: Is the validdation made with javascript?

Comment: No validate by model related to this form

Comment: is it impossible to do that ? :(

Comment: may be a jquery conflict with existing jquery files. Check in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was fixed by my bro seenivasan on Yii Forum , so I will share the code here

_form.php

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'section-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        //'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true), //This is very important
)); ?>

        <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>64)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row buttons">
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
        </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

In controller

```
public function actionCreate()
        {
                $model=new Section;

                // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
                 $this->performAjaxValidation($model);//You have enabled ajax validation. You have to uncomment this line.

                if(isset($_POST['Section']))
                {
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['Section'];
                        if($model->save())
                                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                }

                if(Yii::app()->request->getIsAjaxRequest())
          echo $this->renderPartial('_form',array('model'=>$model),true,true);//This will bring out the view along with its script.

                else $this->render('create',array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                ));
        }
```

Reference link :

[Yii Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/38740-load-view-with-fancybox/page__p__186260__fromsearch__1#entry186260)

[image: Fancy Box]

Answer (score 0):

Just add `'enableClientValidation'=>true,` in the array inside the `beginwidget`.